# Get All Items from Firebase using angularfire2

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have developed a tracking app, its working fine, when user want to track some specific vehicle he selects that vehicle and my app show its location, now i want to display all live vehicles , the problem i am facing is that i am unable to get all vehicles from firebase.Can any one help me what am i missing to do that.

```
/** Function to get firebase DB list for vehNumber*/
public getList(vehNumber): AngularFireList<{}> {
this.vehRef = this._db.list(vehNumber);
return this.vehRef;
}
```

I want to get all vehicles which are live in firebase without passing any parameter but its giving error as it is asking for parametr :

```
public getList(): AngularFireList<{}> {
this.vehRef = this._db.list();
return this.vehRef;
}
```

Comment: See this:https://alligator.io/angular/firebase-crud-operations/

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following database:

```
activeVehicles
          randomId1 
               vehicle: vehicle1
          randomId2 
               vehicle: vehicle2
```

Then you can do the following to get all the live vehicles:

```
this.firebase.list('/activeVehicles').valueChanges().subscribe(active => 
{
   console.log(active);  
     items.forEach(vehicles =>
     { 
        console.log(vehicles) ;
     });
});
```

`vehicles` will contain all the active vehicles that are in the database.

Comment: my database looks like :
http://prntscr.com/o6rwk5
as vehicle numbers are it self nodes

Comment: do u want to retrieve vehicle numbers?

Comment: do this `this.firebase.list().valueChanges().subscribe(active => 
{
   console.log(active);  
     items.forEach(vehicles =>
     { 
        console.log(vehicles) ;
     });
});`